# Why the objects to move are moving to each other and not following each other by 3 seconds space delay?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public List<GameObject> objectsToMove = new List<GameObject>();
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool goForward = true;
    private List<GameObject> objectsToMoveCopy = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        objectsToMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("New Prefab").ToList();

        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();

        if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMove.Count; i++)
            {
                objectsToMove[i].transform.position = pos[index];
            }
        }

        StartCoroutine(AddNew());
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToMoveCopy.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = objectsToMoveCopy[i].transform.position;
            float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            bool stillTraveling = true;
            while (stillTraveling)
            {
                Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
                newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
                distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
                if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
                {
                    // when you hit a waypoint:
                    if (goForward)
                    {
                        bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                        if (!atLastOne) index++;
                        else { index--; goForward = false; }
                    }
                    else
                    { // going backwards:
                        bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                        if (!atFirstOne) index--;
                        else { index++; goForward = true; }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    stillTraveling = false;
                }
            }

            objectsToMoveCopy[i].transform.position = newPos;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AddNew()
    {
        WaitForSeconds waitThreeSeconds = new WaitForSeconds(3);

        foreach (var objToMove in objectsToMove)
        {
            yield return waitThreeSeconds;
            objectsToMoveCopy.Add(objToMove);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using StartCoroutine and the method AddNew to move each object between the waypoints every 3 seconds.

The logic :

- First object to move from the List is start moving from the first position.
- After 3 seconds the second object to move from the List is start moving from the first position.
- The goal is to make that each object will start moving from the first position after 3 seconds following the first moving object before him so in the end I will have the objects moving with spoaces of 3 seconds between them.

The problem :

- The first object is start moving after 3 seconds from the first position then the second and third and the resto f objects are start moving but from the last moved object and the other objects that already move are get merged with the other objects in the end I have a group of all the objects to move are moving together.

The same behave I want to be if they are moving in reverse.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what exactly the problem is. It's pretty hard to understand everything. The only thing I get is that they seem to be moving all to the same point with a 3second delay instead of moving to each other with a 3 second delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objects merge, since you only have one index for the objects' target position, meaning all objects move towards the same point, not each object towards it's respective next point on the path. This results in a merge as soon as the first object turns around and runs backwards.

It would be best to split your logic into two classes, since otherwise you'd have to keep track of every object's path separately, meaning you need an `int[] indices` for the current target position of each object, another array for the `goForward` bools and so on for every new property you introduce.

Controller:

```
public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart;

    public List<MoveOnCurvedLines> movingObjects = new List<MoveOnCurvedLines>();

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3[] positions = GetPositions();

        movingObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("New Prefab").Select(go => go.GetComponent<MoveOnCurvedLines>().ToList();

        foreach (MoveOnCurvedLines obj in movingObjects)
        {
            obj.Init(positions, speed, moveToFirstPositionOnStart);
        }

        StartCoroutine(TriggerObjects(false));
    }

    Vector3[] GetPositions()
    {
        Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);
        return positions;
    }

    IEnumerator TriggerObjects(bool delayFirstObject)
    {
        WaitForSeconds waitThreeSeconds = new WaitForSeconds(3);

        if (delayFirstObject)
            yield return waitThreeSeconds;

        foreach (MoveOnCurvedLines obj in movingObjects)
        {
            obj.StartMoving();
            yield return waitThreeSeconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Movement logic:

```
public class MoveOnCurvedLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform myTransform;
    private bool initialized;

    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int posIndex = 0;
    private float speed;
    private bool goForward = true;
    private Coroutine moving;

    public void Init(Vector3[] positions, float speed, bool instantlyMoveToFirstPosition)
    {
        myTransform = transform;
        pos = positions;
        this.speed = speed;
        if (instantlyMoveToFirstPosition)
            myTransform.position = positions[0];
        initialized = true;
    }

    public void StartMoving()
    {
        if (initialized && moving == null)
            moving = StartCoroutine(Move());
    }

    public void StopMoving()
    {
        if (moving != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(moving);
            moving = null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Move()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = myTransform.position;
            float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            bool stillTraveling = true;
            while (stillTraveling)
            {
                Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
                newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[posIndex], distanceToTravel);
                distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
                if (newPos == pos[posIndex]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
                {
                    // when you hit a waypoint:
                    if (goForward)
                    {
                        bool atLastOne = posIndex >= pos.Length - 1;
                        if (!atLastOne)
                        {
                            posIndex++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            posIndex--;
                            goForward = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    { // going backwards:
                        bool atFirstOne = posIndex <= 0;
                        if (!atFirstOne)
                        {
                            posIndex--;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            posIndex++; 
                            goForward = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    stillTraveling = false;
                }
            }

            myTransform.position = newPos;
        }
    }
}
```

`MovementController` only provides the necessary data, which all your objects share (e.g. the path), but every `MoveOnCurvedLines` object keeps track of it's progress independently.

Optimizations:

- I cached `transform` in `myTransform`, since Unity's `transform` calls `GetComponent<Transform>()` every time producing unnecessary overhead.
- Moving is done in a coroutine, not in `Update`, since checking n `go` bools every frame n objects do not move is unnecessary.
- I changed your `public` fields to `private` ones getting serialized, since it's best practice to restrict access as much as possible. If you need to access them from another script in your project just make them `public` again.